# Firefox bookmarklet writes return value into page

Tags: firefox, bookmarklet

I have a simple input (text) value manipulation bookmarklet for Firefox

```js
javascript:{let e=document.activeElement;let v=e.value;e.value=v+"xxx"}
```

When I run it in console, it changes an active (focused) element value by adding `xxx` suffix (this is desired behavior) and returns current `element.value`.

[image]

But when used as bookmark this value is written into document = destroys the page.
[image]

Why?

// Edit: It's ran from a bookmark (not directly from Address bar, where javascript is disabled as default)
[image]

### UPDATE

```js
javascript:{let e=document.activeElement;let v=e.value;e.value=v+"xxx";window.alert("xx");}
```

This code does not not write to page, because the last "line" of code `window.alert("xx");` does not return value (`console.log()` etc. works too).

So it seems the problem is returning value from [`String.prototype.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace)

[image]

Comment: I thought about posting it to StackOverflow, but it seems to be Firefox thing. So I choose SuperUser. Feel free to move it if my decision is wrong.

Comment: `void()` is the common practice for bookmarklets you are looking for: `javascript:{let e=document.activeElement;let v=e.value;e.value=v+"xxx"; void(0)}`